# Can't select item in list

Tags: android, list, select

I wanted to create application where items in list ll be editting when you select item and press in menu "Edit", but items in list dont selecting...

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    final long id = this.getSelectedItemId();

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case IDM_EDIT:
            if (id > 0) {     
                CallEditContactDialog(id);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.toast_notify, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            }
            break;

    }
    return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}
```

Maybe it is working for android 2nd, but i make it for third too and can test it just on tab 8.9 android 3.2...
Sorry for my english and knowledge in android.

Comment: Do you see the Toast notification?

Comment: Implement default behavior for switch. Are you sure that itemId is IDM_EDIT ?

Comment: Yep, i see notification and about IDM_EDIT, not sure of it... So how can i check it?

Comment: @anto111ka then your id is not greater than 1 ;)

Comment: And if you try to debug this code id = 0? Is item indexing from 1?

Comment: How do you build your menu ? you could use negative numbers for example...

Comment: For now i m not okay in SDK and dont uderstand bit of your suggestion, but anyway... Now i go to debug and found 1 line which how i think is important - 01-26 23:20:45.242: W/InputManagerService(287): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4094ef10

Comment: m... you override the function and want to change something that contains in list in main programm? Are you sure that getSelectedItemId is for you list ? I think you have to save id of item when touch the list item but not menu item ?

Comment: @dilix hm, that is really question, i think its item id...  And one more - i copied this code from site where author said that everething work fine, but on android 2nd... He cant check it on 3rd...

Comment: @anto111ka  you can send me you code (dilix@yandex.ru) (if it's not secret and commercial =) ) and i can test it on 2.3.3

Comment: @dilix sent you it. Thank you for a future. Code is just for a testing, not secret :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am i right that you have some items in the list in activity, you want to pres on one of it then press menu button and press Edit ?

I think you have to save id when press on the item in list and then perform change action with this id onOptionsItemSelected...

Comment: Yep, you are absolutely right... Can you give me some hints about your suggestion (how to make it), i tried find some info about it in google but nothing. :(

Comment: I have to now how do you implement your list. If you use listView you can find solution here:http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html